# CORS error in jQuery GET

Tags: javascript, jquery, cors

I am trying to do a get call and log the response. But, it is showing CORS error. I am using jQuery. I tried by setting header but it is still not working.

```
var site = "google.com";

$.get('https://' + site, function(res) {

res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
console.log (res);

});
```

Comment: These settings must be done on the server-side, not on your request. The server needs to add that header to the response. See more at https://enable-cors.org/.

Answer (score 0):

For your request to work, you need to set the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` on the host, not the client your making the request from. If you are using a third party API, you may require to provide some kind of Authorization header to make the request successfully.

If you want to try this out locally, try running a express server under a different host name and setting the response headers to allow other origins to see the different cases.

**Reference:**
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS